# how to reinstall pip or change directory path

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip

I have been getting the same error whenever I tried to install modules using pip, using mac. I think it may because I was changing the path and accidentally change the pip path. I tried installing pip again through many methods but it still didn't work, especially when I tried to use pip to reinstall. I was wondering would there be any chance that I can maybe fix it with changing the path or something? Thanks

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 188, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 454, in run
    self._handle_target_dir(
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 460, in _handle_target_dir
    ensure_dir(target_dir)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 142, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/urs'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what paths you were changing but it seems there may be a misspelling in there. I see a mkdir on `/urs`. There is a `/usr` and one would expect python stuff in there.

Comment: because i have notice that whenever i install a module using pip, I'm not able to import it within python. Then I realized that pip and where my modules are located have a different locations. that's why I tried to change the path of pip which I failed in.

Comment: would there be anyway that i can completely uninstall pip and python and reinstall it again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for reinstall: `pip uninstall pip` and then write in google `get-pip.py`, download it and run it.

Comment: I have tried, i cant install/uninstall any modules using pip. it just gives me the same error

Comment: Then delete pip from path where you placed it and run `get-pip.py`

Comment: like as in where pip path is linked to?

Comment: Where pip is located

Comment: and where pip path is linked to

Comment: I have tried, but it didnt work. i deleted both pip3 and pip file. when install using get-pup.py, it just shown me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall pip via:
`pip uninstall pip` if you use pip3 try this: `pip3 uninstall pip3`and then reinstall it: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`the fresh reinstall should fix your problems.

Comment: I have tried, i cant install/uninstall any modules using pip. it just gives me the same error